# Issue with displaying a tree graph after deleting a vertex

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, trees, igraphm

Say, I have an expression tree:

`g =  IGExpressionTree[ {{{1,2},{{3,4},{5,6}}},7}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`

From that tree I want to delete all the vertices that aren't the parents of any other vertices,i.e. vertices which are not source of any arrows in such tree, so I do:

`VertexDelete[g,Complement[VertexList[g],First/@EdgeList[g]]]`

But then instead of getting a modified tree as an output I get:

[image]

Can someone help me understand why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: Which Mathematica version?

Comment: @Szabolcs  I'm using 11.3

Comment: does `vc=AssociationThread[VertexList[g],  GraphEmbedding[g]]; SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, _?(VertexOutDegree[g,#]==0&)], VertexCoordinates->{v_:>vc[v]}]` work?

Comment: @kglr It does! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be a bug in Mathematica's `VertexDelete`, or maybe the `"LayeredEmbedding"` `GraphLayout`.

To work around it, use `Graph[VertexDelete[...], GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]`.

Alternatively, use `IGExpressionTree[..., GraphRoot -> Automatic]`. The problem has to do with the `GraphRoot` option, which here is meant to ensure that the tree is drawn with the correct root. You can ensure the correct root in another way:

```
g = IGExpressionTree[{{{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}}}, 7}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphRoot -> Automatic, 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> {}}]
```

This has a problem too, unfortunately: applying IndexGraph to the result won't render in Mathematica 11.3 and earlier as the vertex name for the root vertex was hard coded. In v12.0, this is no longer a problem, so perhaps I should change IGraph/M to use this method in M12.0+.

Comment: I thought it might have been a bug. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @amator2357 I would consider this a bug, but I must note that the `GraphRoot` option I am using is not documented. I expect this to be pointed out when I report this to Wolfram ... Unfortunately, I was not able to find a more robust solution for setting the root than using `GraphRoot` for M11.3 and earlier. Now that 12.0 fixes many graph-related problems, I will change `IGExpressionTree` to use a different (and documented) method for that version.  For M11.3, keep using the workaround I mentioned. I doubt that there will be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

```
vc = AssociationThread[VertexList @ g, GraphEmbedding @ g]; 
SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, _?(VertexOutDegree[g, #] == 0 &)], 
  VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> vc[v]}]
```

also works (per amator2357's confirmation in the comments).